# How do I host Apache NiFi on my website through my webhosting server

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to be able to upload and access a NiFi instance remotely and i figured the best way to do it is through my web hosting or similar, through a webpage.

Is this possible? Does it always have to be done on localhost?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a host that is capable of running *nix and Java 8. It is not likely a normal "web host" will give you the privileges you need, but options include AWS, Azure, DigitalOcean, Linode, etc.